# How to update content in a page using webhook?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, webhooks

I'm trying to update content in an active loaded page using webhook response.

Earlier, I used to trigger the function using setTimeout for every 5 secs but noticed its kind of increasing server load. So, now whenever there is a change on the database a webhook will be triggered through which I will update the content on the loaded page without refreshing it.

But how do I tell a webhook URL to change/update content on another page.?

so far code goes as :
**PAGE#1:**

```
<div id="loader_div">Some content</div>
<script>
function loadlink(){
    $('#loader_div').load('loading.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load

setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() 
}, 5000); // this will run after every 5 seconds
</script>
```

**loading.php**

```
<p>some other content that i got from database</p>
```

Now the webhook URL is loading.php which gets the new update from the database, but how do I trigger the 'loadlink();' on the page1 without refreshing it and using set timeout..?

Comment: The webhook is a mechanism for the service to notify your server of something happening. If you now in turn want the server to update all clients currently showing your page, that is a completely independent issue, that has little to do with the webhook itself. You should go look into keywords like HTML5 Server-Sent events or Websockets for that.

Comment: So, I can not trigger a server request function (in the above case loadlink()) from a webhook response..?

Comment: No, you can not. The webhook has absolutely nothing to do with any page that might currently be displayed on some client.